# HTML5 video control (only volume)

Tags: html, video, volume

So i'm working on a website. I want to include a full background video. The only thing i don't know is how to set up the control panel. If i use `<video controls autoplay> </video>` tag its shows the video's timeline. I only want to make a button where user can decide that she/he wants to hear the music or not. Here is my html code.

```
<section id="one" class="wrapper style11 special">
<a href="#" target="_blank" > <video controls autoplay loop muted class="bgvideo" id="bgvideo" > 
<source src="images/ok.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
</video> </a>
</section>
```

Comment: My opinion would be to hide video controls (`<video>` without the attribute `controls`) and to use JavaScript to controls the video with a custom button.

Comment: you should create button, which could add or remove 'muted' argument to <video>

Comment: create it yourself : `<input type="checkbox" id="muter"/>`and `document.getElementById('muter').onchange=function(){document.querySelector('video').muted=this.checked;}` should do the trick